# PHP string is not joining together

Tags: php

PHP code:

```
    $checked = $this->input->post('checkbox');
    $status = $this->input->post('adsstatus');
    if(in_array('all', $checked)){
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM ads'; 
    }
    else{
        $finalnumber = count($checked) - 1;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ';
            if($i == $finalnumber){
               $query .= 'ID = $checked[$i] '; 
            }
            else{
                $query .= 'ID = $checked[$i] || '; 
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($checked);
    echo $query;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => electronics
    [1] => kitchen
    [2] => decoratives
    [3] => homedecor
    [4] => furnitures
    [5] => toys
    [6] => vehicles
)
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ID = $checked[$i]
```

the string of variable $query is not joining together. the value of the variable checked is 7 it executing my nested else condition but still string is not joining together. How to resolve it please help me right now I am a helpless

Comment: It should be `"ID = {$checked[$i]} "`. You need to use double quotes, and put `{}` around the variable.

Comment: Use double quotes -> `$query .= "ID = {$checked[$i]}";`

Comment: @Barmar I am a talking about a string is not joining together.

Comment: It is joining together. It's just not replacing `$checked[$i]` with its value, because you used the wrong type of quotes. Variables are only replaced inside double quotes, not single quotes. Didn't you read the answers to the question I linked to?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating queries by joining strings together anyway. You should use a prepared query with `bind_param()`.

Comment: @Barmar still it not working I replaced it.

Comment: Edit your question and add the new version of your code at the end.

Comment: BTW, you should learn to use `foreach()`, it makes looping over arrays much simpler.

Comment: @Barmar SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ID = toys it is my latest output.

Comment: You need quotes around the value, since it's a MYSQL string. `$query .= "ID = '{$checked[$i]}'";`

Comment: Also, instead of using `ID = x OR ID = y OR ...` you should use `WHERE ID IN (x, y, ...)`.

Comment: @Barmar man string is not joining it is my issue.

Comment: Edit the question and show your new code. Otherwise I can't help you.\